# Office randomly prompts for passwords

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I'm experiencing an issue with some users, using both office home and business '19 and office home and business '21, on windows 10 and 11 machines.

These users get seemingly at random a prompt asking for the password of the mailbox from outlook, and sometimes from teams too. It can happen once per day, or every 20 minutes, there doesn't seem to be any regularity in when it happens. Once they input the password, they get asked if they want to log in on all MS apps, as if it was the first log in on that machine.

So far I've tried the following:

- Launched authchk.exe to check if it was a problem with modern authentication, but to no avail
- Did an online repair of Office, which seemed to solve the problem for about a week, then the issue presented itself again
- Deleted the credentials saved in the MS Credential Manager, restarted the computers and logged back in
- Deleted the profile in outlook and logged back in
- Logged out of office, uninstalled both office and teams, and reinstalled them
- Increased the office licenses both for '19 and '21

I'm starting to run out of ideas at the moment.

EDIT: the mailboxes are on office365 business basic

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to an Exchange On-Premises mailbox, see the following articles for additional troubleshooting:
[Outlook prompts for password when Modern Authentication is enabled](https://support.microsoft.com/help/3126599)

Additionally, you can view the following forum thread for common causes:
[Why does Outlook keep prompting for password](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcd2d9c2-1a1b-4446-bf32-69fee8cdf11b/why-does-outlook-keep-prompting-for-password?forum=outlook)

Comment: Thank you! i'm trying some of the solutions posted in the forum, i'll keep you posted

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.